# Should I plumb Cancellation Tokens through all of my class methods in an asp.net core 3.1 web API?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net-core-3.1, design-principles, cancellation-token

I've been building a web server in asp.net core 3.1 for a little while and I've started to notice (and frankly, dislike) that Im plumbing cancellation tokens through my application. I came up with a solution to this "problem" (it is and it isn't) and am seeking opinons.

First, just so we're all on the same page - let's recap the request pipeline:

- A request hits the server and the asp.net core framework instantiates an `HttpContext`
- The framework instantiates a `CancellationToken` and attaches it to the `HttpContext.RequestAborted` property, (which, yes lol, has the type `CancellationToken`)
- Some mapping happens behind the scenes in the framework, and a controller is resolved from the DI container (the controllers are registered as services)
- The controller method is called, decorated by a pipeline of middleware through which the `HttpContext` instance is passed
- The framework performs model binding on the `HttpContext` instance (taking from the route params, query params, body, header, etc ) and then attempts to pass the results to the method discovered during mapping
- Model binding results that fit the signature are injected (or passed, whichever word you prefer) as well as the CancellationToken taken from the `HttpContext.RequestAborted` property.

Second - here is some context on my problem:

I use Autofac for dependency injection, and I learned at some point that you can give dependencies (class instances) Lifetime Scopes, which will dictate how long lived a class instance is. I also developed a practical or intuitive perspective, which is a little different, and also differs by scope type. Examples probably illustrate this best:

- a single instance for the lifetime of the application (where you can store data, and then resolve it anywhere else in the application at any time),
- a unique instance each time the type is injected, so no state is shared between injected instances
- others!

Since this is an asp.net core 3.1 mvc/web api, a lifetimeScope is available from Autofac that allows you to resolve the same instance from the container from within the context of the current request (in other words, any code executing for any one given request will resovle the same instance. Different request? Different instance). This is the `.InstancePerLifetimeScope()` scope type in Autofac 6.

Using this information, I realized that I could write a piece of middleware that assignes the `httpContext.RequestAborted` cancellation token to a  transport class that has a lifetime scope of `InstancePerLifetimeScope` and then inject that transport into the places that directly consume the token. In the codebase, this is not very many places (certainly far fewer than all of the plumbed locations).

Here is a minimal set of code that demonstrates what such a no-plumb scenario might be set up like - imagine each class is in its own file:

```
public class SetCancellationTokenTransportMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public SetCancellationTokenTransport(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ITransportACancellationToken transport)
    {
        transport.Assign(context.RequestAborted);
        await next(context);
    }
}



// Autoface module registrations
public class GeneralModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<SomeDependency>().As<ISomeDependency>();
        builder.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<CancellationTokenTransport>().As<ITransportACancellationToken>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}

// mvc controller - cancellation token is not injected
public class Controller
{
    private readonly ISomeDependency dep;

    public Controller(ISomeDependency dep)
    {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    [HttpGet()]
    public async Task<Thing> Get()
    {
        return await dep.Handle();
    }
}

// This gets bypassed -- the cancellation token isn't plumbed through the handle method
public class SomeDependency : ISomeDependency
{
    private readonly Repository repository;
    
    public SomeDependency(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    {

    public async Task Handle() // no token is passed
    {
        return await repository.GetThing(); // no token is passed
    }
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private readonly ITransportACancellationToken transport;
    private readonly DbContext context;

    public Repository(ITransportACancellationToken transport, DbContext context)
    {
        this.transport = transport;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task<Thing> GetThing()
    {
        // The transport passes the token here - bypassing the calling class[es]

        return await context.Things.ToListAsync(transport.CancellationToken); 
    }
}
```

So my question generally is - what do you think about this approach to providing Cancellation tokens directly to token consumers (and not their intermediaries)? What Pros and Cons you can think of? Have you ever been burnt by this approach? Does anyone use this in their applications or those they've worked on?

One argument against this pattern I can think of are cases where you need explicitely deprive a code path of a cancellation token. However, the repository here could also technically be designed in a such a way that allows one to choose if cancellation is allowed. Using a Unit of Work pattern, this is also partially mitigates (and the transport class would be injected into the unit of work).

I would very much like to hear some experienced perspectives on this one. General thoughts are of course welcome as well.

Answer (score 2):

> What Pros and Cons you can think of?

The only Pro is you have less boilerplate code.

The primary Con is that you also need to be aware of and hook into all desired changes to the token. As you noted, some code paths should *ignore* cancellation. It's also common to have a substitute token in some code paths, e.g., a Polly-based retry/timer handler. To handle those more complex cases, your transport type should hold an immutable stack of CTs rather than just a single value.

It's also (theoretically) possible that the CT flow may not exactly mimic async method flows, which transport types (using `AsyncLocal<T>` under the hood) are intrinsically tied to. That would be a very rare situation, though.

A secondary Con is that any kind of transport is a kind of "magic" and increases the mental burden of reading the code.

> Does anyone use this in their applications or those they've worked on?

Not in apps I've worked on, but I have seen the idea before.